# what are database for downloading Spatial Data?

Tags: data, econometrics

I am trying to find a good database for Spatial Data. 
What are the examples of this kind of data? IS it always related to geography?
Any Spatial data related to finance, economics and statistics?

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: I know that companies use voronoi diagrams of all of their store locations and population density maps in order to determine (eg) the optimal placement of a new store. This is more strategy than finance, but it is one example of how geospatial data is used in business. I'm not sure that this would be useful for anyone outside of the organization to do, though. Obtaining the data is, as always, a matter of writing a script to scrape a company website or paying someone who has already done it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to take a look at some of the [supply chain data](http://www.factset.com/campaigns/revere), I personally have no idea how useful this is.

Another interesting area is the import export data sets. There are many [interesting papers on this](http://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0301015).